# Write a method that stores strings in a string array with indices from 0 to a user specified end index (get it from the command line) using a loop

Tags: java

In other words How do I store strings in a string array in the I am asking?

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    String[] anArray;

    int end = input.nextInt();

    anArray = new String[end];

    String buzz = "Buzz", fizz = "Fizz", pop = "Pop!";
```

Comment: why create an `int[]` when you want to store `String`? Have you checked the doc? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: Write another method that will print out the array using a loop, with each index on a new line. yes but Im still having trouble with this.

Comment: @RandyGarcia is your assignment to read in the Strings from input?  Or is it something like the answer I posted?

Comment: Write a method that stores strings in a string array with indices from 0 to a user specified end index (get it from the command line) using a loop. When the index is divisible by 3, store "Fizz" in that index. When the index is divisible by 4, store "Buzz" in it, when the index is divisble by 5, store "Pop" in it. If the index is divisible by both 3 and 4, store "Fizz Buzz". If it's divisible by both 3 and 5, store "Fizz Pop!". If it's divisible by all 3, store "Fizz Buzz Pop!".
Write another method that will print out the array using a loop, with each index on a new line.

Answer (score 0):

Use Utils Arrays class to copy the array upto sepcific length
 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

```
String[] anArray;

int end = input.nextInt();

anArray = new String[end];

String buzz = "Buzz", fizz = "Fizz", pop = "Pop!";
anArray = java.util.Arrays.copyOf(buzz,end);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Get the input `size`, so you know the size of the array
2. Create an array of strings using `String[]`
3. Loop from `0` to `size` (exclusive), using `input.next()` to get each string
4. Store each string in the correspondent position in the array
5. Print the array to check if it's right using `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array))`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 String[] anArray;   
 Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
 int noofInputs = sc.nextInt();
 anArray = new String[noofInputs];
 for(int i=0; i<noofInputs; i++)
    anArray[i] = sc.next();    // to store string inputs in an array
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not completely clear from your question, but I suspect that you're looking for something like this:

```
public class Solution {

    public static String[] strArray;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

      FizzBuzzPop();

      print();


    }


    public static void FizzBuzzPop(){

       try{
            String buzz = "Buzz", fizz = "Fizz", pop = "Pop!";

            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            int end = input.nextInt();
            //int end = 30; //testing

            strArray = new String[end+1];

            for (int i = 0; i <= end; i++) {
                if (i % 3 == 0 && i % 4 == 0 && i % 5 == 0){
                   strArray[i] = new String(fizz + " " + buzz + " " + pop);
                }
                else if (i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0){
                   strArray[i] = new String(fizz + " " + pop);
                }
                else if (i % 3 == 0 && i % 4 == 0){
                   strArray[i] = new String(fizz + " " + buzz);
                }
                else if (i % 3 == 0){
                    strArray[i] = new String(fizz);
                }
                else if (i % 4 == 0){
                    strArray[i] = new String(buzz);
                }
                else if (i % 5 == 0){
                    strArray[i] = new String(pop);
                }
                else{
                    strArray[i] = new Integer(i).toString();
                }

            }
       }
       catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Exception thrown  :" + e);
       }    

    }


  public static void print(){

    for (int i = 0; i < strArray.length; i++){
      System.out.println(strArray[i]);
    }

  }
}
```

Output for input of 30:

```
Fizz Buzz Pop!
1
2
Fizz
Buzz
Pop!
Fizz
7
Buzz
Fizz
Pop!
11
Fizz Buzz
13
14
Fizz Pop!
Buzz
17
Fizz
19
Buzz
Fizz
22
23
Fizz Buzz
Pop!
26
Fizz
Buzz
29
Fizz Pop!
```